# Return value from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hi I am using vs 2008 doing a winforms app in vb.net. I have a database with a single table, that has two columns, in it and a stored procedure. The stored procedure is supposed to take an input value, match that value against one column in the table and then return the corresponding value from the other column; except it doesnt.It returns 1 or 0 please can anyone tell me why

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getgamenumber(@outputnumber bigint OUTPUT,
                                  @inputnumber bigint) 
AS 

  SELECT @outputnumber = ggnumber
    FROM statstable
   WHERE gindex = @inputnumber 

  RETURN  @outputnumber
```

and the stored proc is called thus

```
With cmdgetgame
  .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  .CommandText = "getgamenumber"
  .Parameters.Add("@outputnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = outputnumber
  .Parameters("@outputnumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputnumber", inputvalue)
  returnvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
End With
```

Thanks for all and any help.

sorry for the confusion my vb code now looks like this

```
 With cmdgetgame
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "getgamenumber"
                .Parameters.Add("@outputnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = outputnumber
                .Parameters("@outputnumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputnumber", inputvalue)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                returnvalue = cmdgetgame.Parameters("@outputnumber").Value
            End With
```

and my stored proc like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getgamenumber
( @outputnumber bigint ,
@inputnumber bigint) 
AS 
    SELECT       ggnumber
    FROM            statstable
    WHERE        (gindex = @inputnumber)
```

but  I still dont get the value I expect.

Comment: If you know you wanted to return a single value, why not use a scalar Function instead?

Comment: have you tried running the sp directly in sql server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blimey I've done it. Thanks to all who offered help, it showed me how skewed my initial attempt had been. My vb code now looks like this

```
 With cmdgetgame
                .Connection = _con
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "getgamenumber"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputnumber", inputvalue)
                .Parameters.Add("@retvalue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
                returnvalue = cmdgetgame.Parameters("@retvalue").Value


            End With
```

and my stored proc now looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getgamenumber
(
@inputnumber int
) 
as
    declare @retvalue int 

    SELECT       @retvalue = ggnumber
    FROM         statstable
    WHERE        (gindex = @inputnumber)

    return @retvalue
```

Pheweee I thought I would never get there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to use `@outputnumber` as both an output parameter and a return value.

You don't need to set a value to that parameter in VB.NET when you set it to an output parameter.

Then, you don't need the return statement. (and you shouldn't use RETURN in T-SQL to get values out, anyway)

To get the output value:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
returnvalue = cmdgetgame.Parameters("@outputnumber").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could execute the stored procedure with `ExecuteNonQuery`, and then check the value of the output parameter after.  Like:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
returnvalue = .Parameters("@outputnumber").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

cmd.ExecuteScalar() will return the 1st column of the 1st row of the result set.
Amend your procedure to:

```
SELECT @outputnumber
```

instead of

```
 RETURN @outputnumber
```

Comment: That would leave a stored procedure with an output parameter that expects you to read its result set.  It would work though :-)

Comment: oppps like this    With cmdgetgame
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    .CommandText = "getgamenumber"
                    .Parameters.Add("@outputnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = outputnumber
                    .Parameters("@outputnumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputnumber", inputvalue)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    returnvalue = cmdgetgame.Parameters("@outputnumber").Value
                End With