# cmd.executenonquery is returning -1 in vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net

I am just inserting a record in sqlserver database using stored procedure.
In this code Binddata() is the method where i have binbed the gridview with records.

here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click

    sqlSP = "INSERT_E_CLIENTMASTER_REC"
    strConnection = _
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectstring").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConnection)

    conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlSP, conn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.Add(
        New SqlParameter("@CLIENTCODE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, _
            ParameterDirection.Input, False, 0, 0, "", _
            DataRowVersion.Proposed, txtclientcode.Text))
    'cmd.Parameters.Add( _
    '    New SqlParameter("@CLIENT_WEBXID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, _
    '        Convert.ToString(txtwebxid.Text))) _
    cmd.Parameters.Add( _
        New SqlParameter("@CLIENT_WEBXID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, _
            ParameterDirection.Input, False, 0, 0, "", _
            DataRowVersion.Proposed, txtwebxid.Text))

    cmd.Parameters.Add( _
        New SqlParameter("@ToEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, _
            ParameterDirection.Input, False, 0, 0, "", _
            DataRowVersion.Proposed, txttoemail.Text))

    cmd.Parameters.Add( _
        New SqlParameter("@ClientName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, _
        ParameterDirection.Input, _
        False, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, txtclientname.Text))

    cmd.Parameters.Add(_
        New SqlParameter("@CcEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, _
        ParameterDirection.Input, False, 0, 0, "", _
        DataRowVersion.Proposed, txtccname.Text))

    Dim i As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i < 0) Then
        BindData()
        MsgBox("Record Inserted successfully ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        txtclientcode.Text = ""
        txtwebxid.Text = ""
        txttoemail.Text = ""
        txtclientname.Text = ""
        txtccname.Text = ""

    Else
        MsgBox("Record Not Inserted successfully ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End If
```

End Sub

In this code cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is returning -1 so i have given (i<0) condition actually it should be positive value when rows are affected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is the record saved to the database? If so, then that's because the stored procedure is not returning a value.

[ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE
>   statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the
>   command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the
>   return value includes the number of
>   rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of
>   rows affected by the trigger or
>   triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If
>   a rollback occurs, the return value is
>   also -1.

If you need to return a value from the stored procedure, look at this [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907681/return-value-from-stored-procedure)

On a side note - Look into using the "[USING Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)" for your connections

Comment: Hello. I am not returning any value from stored procedure.but ExecuteNonQuery()method returns number of rows affected which is a positive number. But I am getting -1 value that is wrong, so is my code correct. Thanks for answering

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery() will return rows affected when performing an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. The stored procedure you have is not returning a value that's why you are geting -1 as the return value.

Comment: I have written stored procedure for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. Records are getting inserted/updated/deleted, but if i give if(i>0) condition then it enters the else block not the if block b'coz i value on debugging is -1.I don't know whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line "SET NOCOUNT ON;" from your SProc.

SET NOCOUNT (Transact-SQL):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx