# Integer value changing to -1 from 0 after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: asp.net

I create a table in the database dynamically. The user enters their name as they wish and selects their language using a `RadioButton`. The problem is that after executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` the value of `i` is changing to `-1` from `0`. This shows that the table couldnt be created but when I go to the database it has been created successfully. Please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
protected void btnpaper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconn"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                con.Open();
                char[] arr = new char[] {'n','g','l','i','s','h'};
                string str = "CREATE TABLE " + Label1.Text.Trim() + 
                             txtpaperset.Text.Trim()+ rbtnEng.Text.TrimEnd(arr) +
                             "(" + "quesNo int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " + 
                             "question varchar(1000) NOT NULL," + 
                             "ansA varchar(500) NOT NULL, " + 
                             "ansB varchar(500) NOT NULL, " + 
                             "ansC varchar(500) NOT NULL, " + 
                             "ansD varchar(500) NOT NULL, " + 
                             "rightAns varchar(50) NOT NULL " + ")";                    
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    lblerrormsg.Visible = true;
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblerrormsg.Text = "Table Not Created Please Try with Different Name!";                        
                    con.Close();
                }                

        }
        catch (System.Exception excep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
        }      
    }
```

Comment: This code is prone to SQL Injection

Comment: **Exactly** the same question: [cmd.ExecuteNonQuery value of i integer is going -1 from 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619919/cmd-executenonquery-value-of-i-integer-is-going-1-from-0)

Answer (score 1):

There is no any problem with your code, everything is correct.
Please check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619919/cmd-executenonquery-value-of-i-integer-is-going-1-from-0),

**

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

**

Comment: Anandkumar is correct, here is another source stating the same thing http://books.google.com.au/books?id=4fYEPmvmCM4C&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=executenonquery+returns+negative+1+create+table&source=bl&ots=D5usl2nhRz&sig=uwipw3ICU6q_hPfY_O9_rRwX1vE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3RKFUISdNciZiAeDwYHoDQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=executenonquery%20returns%20negative%201%20create%20table&f=false

Answer (score -1):

use this

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;